Comala confluence tasks get restored after the page update/edit
On my confluence page i have added 3 tasks for three people. They have completed the tasks. The problem is that anytime I update the confluence page the tasks reaper. Is there any possible solution to this?
{state:APPROVED|final=true|updated=APPROVED|hideselection=true}
    {task:name=Kakovost: Prebrano in potrjeno|assignee=XXXXXXX@si.XXXXXXX.com}
    {task:name=Lean: Prebrano in potrjeno|assignee=XXXXXXX@si.XXXXXXX.com}
    {task:name=Varnostni inženir: Prebrano in potrjeno|assignee=XXXXXXX@si.XXXXXXX.com}
{state}

Couldn't find a solution.
